# select observation by group with max date SQL via R

Tags: sql, r, group-by

I have data in a similar structure as shown below.  This is in R code but if you can just write the query without the R stuff thats fine too.

I have multiple groups and there are dates for each observation.  I want to select a single row from each group that corresponds to the max date (most recent date) for that particular group.  There are no duplicate dates.

```
Df = data.frame(dates=c('2012-01-25','2012-08-20','2013-07-31','2013-05-30'), 
                group=c('a','a','b','b'), 
                value=c(1,2,3,4))

Library(sqldf)
(Desiredresults = Df[2:3,])
# 1 2012-08-20     a     2
# 2 2013-07-31     b     3
```

Comment: I don't understand, do you need a SQL code or an R code?

Answer (score 7):

It's not clear what solution you want R or SQL, so here are both.
First, I'm assuming your `dates` column is of class `Date` as in

```
Df$dates <- as.Date(Df$dates)
```

**SQL**

Using the `sqldf` package you basically have two simple solutions, either explicitly select the columns where `dates` is maximum

```
sqldf('select max(dates) as dates, "group", value from Df group by "group"')
#        dates group value
# 1 2012-08-20     a     2
# 2 2013-07-31     b     3
```

Or you can select *all* the columns

```
sqldf('select * from Df where dates in (select max(dates) from Df group by "group")')
#        dates group value
# 1 2012-08-20     a     2
# 2 2013-07-31     b     3
```

---

**R**

So in R there could many possible solutions

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Df)[, .SD[which.max(dates)], by = group]
#    group      dates value
# 1:     a 2012-08-20     2
# 2:     b 2013-07-31     3
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
Df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(dates == max(dates))

# Source: local data table [2 x 3]
# Groups: group
# 
#        dates group value
# 1 2012-08-20     a     2
# 2 2013-07-31     b     3
```

Or

```
do.call(rbind, by(Df, Df$group, function(x) x[which.max(x$dates), ]))
#         dates group value
# 1: 2012-08-20     a     2
# 2: 2013-07-31     b     3
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know R but your SQL would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable as A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT GROUPS, MAX(DATES) AS MAX_DATE FROM YourTable GROUP BY GROUPS) AS B 
ON A.GROUPS = B.GROUPS AND B.MAX_DATE = A.DATES
```

This would identify the max date for each group (derived table B) then match them with the records from the main table (table A).