# Filter latest date in the year

Tags: r, dplyr, portfolio

The table below is a sample of the data I have. I want to filter by having only rows that have the latest date of that particular year.

From my main dataset I first filtered using the code below, which gave me the data with rows as below:

```
DATA %>%
  mutate(Year = year(report_dt), Month = month(report_dt)) %>% 
  group_by(Year, ID) %>%  
  slice(which.max(as.Date(report_dt, '%m/%d/%Y')))
```

| report_dt | Company | ID | YEAR | MONTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-09-30 | AMAZON COM INC | 02313510 | 2012 | 9 |
| 2012-09-30 | KRAFT FOODS INC | 50075N10 | 2012 | 9 |
| 2012-10-31 | OMNICOM GROUP INC | 68191910 | 2012 | 10 |
| 2012-11-30 | KRAFT FOODS GROUP INC | 50076Q10 | 2012 | 11 |
| 2012-12-31 | ABBOTT LABORATORIES | 00282410 | 2012 | 12 |
| 2012-12-31 | AMERISOURCEBERGEN CORP | 03073E10 | 2012 | 12 |
| 2012-12-31 | APPLE INC | 03783310 | 2012 | 12 |
| 2012-12-31 | BED BATH & BEYOND INC | 07589610 | 2012 | 12 |

The code works for the first step, but now, for example, I only want those rows with '2012-12-31'. I have tried to use `slice` again but I do not think that is how it works. I also tried at the end: `%>% filter(Month == max(Month))` but did not work.

I have grouped them by year because I need to do the same for each year. My end goal is to create portfolios only with the IDs at the latest date of the year if this info helps).
Thanks

EDIT: This is the outcome I would like for the example (then replicate it for each year). Getting rid of the rows that are not in the maximum date of that particular year.

| report_dt | Company | ID | YEAR | MONTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-12-31 | ABBOTT LABORATORIES | 00282410 | 2012 | 12 |
| 2012-12-31 | AMERISOURCEBERGEN CORP | 03073E10 | 2012 | 12 |
| 2012-12-31 | APPLE INC | 03783310 | 2012 | 12 |
| 2012-12-31 | BED BATH & BEYOND INC | 07589610 | 2012 | 12 |

Comment: If you group by both `ID` and `YEAR` you will end up with the same dataframe because they uniquely identify each row in your sample data.

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- tibble::tribble(
    ~report_dt,                 ~Company,        ~ID, ~YEAR, ~MONTH,
  "2012-09-30",         "AMAZON COM INC", "02313510", 2012L,     9L,
  "2012-09-30",        "KRAFT FOODS INC", "50075N10", 2012L,     9L,
  "2012-10-31",      "OMNICOM GROUP INC", "68191910", 2012L,    10L,
  "2012-11-30",  "KRAFT FOODS GROUP INC", "50076Q10", 2012L,    11L,
  "2012-12-31",    "ABBOTT LABORATORIES", "00282410", 2012L,    12L,
  "2012-12-31", "AMERISOURCEBERGEN CORP", "03073E10", 2012L,    12L,
  "2012-12-31",              "APPLE INC", "03783310", 2012L,    12L,
  "2012-12-31",  "BED BATH & BEYOND INC", "07589610", 2012L,    12L
  )

df |> 
  mutate(report_dt = ymd(report_dt)) |> 
  slice_max(report_dt, by = c(ID, YEAR))
#> # A tibble: 8 × 5
#>   report_dt  Company                ID        YEAR MONTH
#>   <date>     <chr>                  <chr>    <int> <int>
#> 1 2012-09-30 AMAZON COM INC         02313510  2012     9
#> 2 2012-09-30 KRAFT FOODS INC        50075N10  2012     9
#> 3 2012-10-31 OMNICOM GROUP INC      68191910  2012    10
#> 4 2012-11-30 KRAFT FOODS GROUP INC  50076Q10  2012    11
#> 5 2012-12-31 ABBOTT LABORATORIES    00282410  2012    12
#> 6 2012-12-31 AMERISOURCEBERGEN CORP 03073E10  2012    12
#> 7 2012-12-31 APPLE INC              03783310  2012    12
#> 8 2012-12-31 BED BATH & BEYOND INC  07589610  2012    12
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

So I find this solution for my problem, if it does not work, I will fix or change it. I removed the grouping by ID and only grouped by Year.
After the first part of the code I then wrote:

```
DF %>% group_by(Year) %>%  filter(report_dt == max(report_dt))
```

I used it based on what I found here by @DavidArenburg: [select observation by group with max date SQL via R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614779/select-observation-by-group-with-max-date-sql-via-r)